# How pass value in URL and How get value from URl in React JS

Tags: reactjs

**How to Pass value in URL in react js and How to Get Value from URL in React js**
**step 1. Write a code in Link/Button**

```
<Link to={{pathname:`/MediaLandingPage/${props.data.id}`}}>{props.linkName}</Link>
```

**Step 2. Set in Router path**

```
<Route path="/MediaLandingPage/:id" component={MediaLandingPage} />
```

**Step 3. Create Page MediaLandingPage**

```
const MediaLandingPage =(props)=>{
    const id =props.match.params.id
    var ImageData = require('../../Media/image.js')
    var data = ImageData.default
    console.log("Media :",data)
    if(data[id].id==id){
        return<div className=""> 
                    <div><Image src={data[id].imageSrc} className="img-fluid"/></div>
                    <div>{data[id].title}</div>
                    <div>{data[id].description}</div>

                </div>
    }else
    {
        return<div>Sorry</div>
    }
}
export default MediaLandingPage
```

**step 4. Data image.js File**

```
import safeCitizens from "../../assets/images/safeCitizens.png" 
export default[
    {
        id:0,
        imageSrc:safeCitizens,
        title:"name",
        shortDescription:"asfddasf",
        description:"chandra veer singh rathorchandra veer singh rathor"
    },
    {
        id:1,
        imageSrc:safeCitizens,
        title:"name",
        shortDescription:"asfddasf",
        description:"chandra veer singh rathorchandra veer singh rathor"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        imageSrc:safeCitizens,
        title:"name",
        shortDescription:"asfddasf",
        description:"chandra veer singh rathorchandra veer singh rathor"
    } 
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question looks more like a guide/tutorial than a question. If you have a question, please edit your post with some more information. If not, please note that SO is a Q/A site, not a traditional wiki.

Comment: what do you use for route, react-router or react-router-dom? and which version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

Step 1 : Pass your id here directly to route

```
<Link to={`/MediaLandingPage/${props.data.id}`}>{props.linkName}</Link>
```

Step 2 : access your data using

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Solution 2 : [You can refer my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771334/11982418)

```
 you can directly pass your id with link
```